# Zend form _request->getParams() does param exist?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I'm sure this is very simple.We have an ajax call to a controller. The call passes in a value pair - an identifier AND a value. I need to know the name of the identifier as well as the value so that I can do this:

```
      switch ($identifier) {
    case 'country':
        //set value for something
        break;
    case 'region':
        //set value for something else
        break;
}
```

I would prefer not to pass an additional value in because it's not necessary.

I tried this and, apart from being disgusting convoluted code, it didn't work!

```
      $requestparams=$this->_request->getParams();
      list($controller,$action,$module,$levelpair)=$requestparams;
      list ($level,$id)=$levelpair;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $requestparams=$this->_request->getParams();
  foreach($requestparams as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
    case 'country':
        //set value for something
        break;
    case 'region':
        //set value for something else
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's safer to get the parameters via controller methods instead of accessing the protected members directly. Also, from what I can tell, `switch` isn't the best approach.

Try:

```
$requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

if (isset($requestParams['country'])) {
     //do something
}

if (isset($requestParams['region'])) {
     //do something
}
```